# How to implement index rollover properties/condition in ES using spring-data-elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-elasticsearch

How can I add the following property values in elastic search when using spring-data-elasticsearch?

1. The maximum size or age at which you want to roll over to a new index.
2. The point at which the index is no longer being updated and the number of primary shards can be reduced.
3. When to force a merge to permanently delete documents marked for deletion.
4. The point at which the index can be moved to less performant hardware.
5. The point at which the availability is not as critical and the number of replicas can be reduced.
6. When the index can be safely deleted.

Currently, I creating dynamic index name using:

@Document(indexName = "#{@esConfig.getIndexName()}", shards = 1, replicas = 0, refreshInterval = "5s", createIndex = false)

Answer (score 0):

Index lifecycle Actions are currently not supported in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

You'd need to implement this using the functions that the Elasticsearch client offers.